# c# waveform - how to display microphone data

Tags: c#, audio, typeconverter, waveform

I'm trying to **display** a waveform ( i recorded my self in the **microphone**).

The keep the data in a **byte** array.

In addition my sample rate is 44100 and the sample size is **16bit**.

My array contains only positive values, but in some examples i saw that the values are between *-1.0 to 1.0*. Why is that?
In addition, If my sample size is 16 bit and i'm using a byte array - i need to make a conversion.
 This is what i tried to do so far:

```
    double[] x = new double[Arc.Buffer.Count / 2];
    byte[] y = new byte[2];

                for (i = 0; i < Arc.Buffer.Count; i++)
                {
                    Array.Copy(Arc.Buffer.ToArray(), 2*i, y, 0, 2);
                    x[i] = (double)((y[1] << 8) | (y[0] & 0x00FF));
                }
```

But after this code, my x array contain huge values (and not -1.0 to 1.0).

I'm new in this subject and i will appreciate any help! (:

Comment: I don't know why you get the huge values, but for displaying the data in a curve I can recommend Oxyplot. I've used it before and it has a lot of cool and well performing functions

Comment: I have a library for display. i just want to know if my logic is wrong... in my example i convert every 2 bytes (beacuse i'm using sample size of 16 bits) to double. Am i right?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any experience with working with bytes. Did you debug the code to see what exactly happens?

Comment: Well it comes down to that you have to know how the data is stored in the byte array. It could be `short`s or unsigned `short` or a compressed sort of small range floating point or whatever. Just raw casting byte data to a `double` might or might not get you to where you need to be depending how the original data looks like. If I would have to guess, probably not. Before you figure the original data format out there is not a whole lot of advise we can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is PCM data, there are a number of WAV/RIFF formats possible.  If your sample size is 16 bits, the values you're reading are going to be signed, between -32,768 and 32,767.

A quick search for "wav riff formats" turned up [a resource](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html) regarding parsing digital audio data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are processing 16-bit signed samples then the values are going to be between -32768 and 32767. To get in the range of -1.0 to 1.0 double precision you need to divide by 32768.0

```
double[] x = new double[Arc.Buffer.Count / 2];
byte[] y = new byte[2];

for (i = 0; i < Arc.Buffer.Count; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(Arc.Buffer.ToArray(), 2*i, y, 0, 2);
    x[i] = ((y[1] << 8) | (y[0] & 0x00FF)) / 32768.0;
}
```